# angular onpush component rerenders only with async pipe inside template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I have my component with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` strategy.

Im passing data from parent via `async` pipe, when that data change component refuse to rerender.

When im instead of using `async` pipe in parent pass obvservable and use `async` pipe inside of child template, rerenders are called correctly.

Anyone knows why that happens (angular v9)?
I guess it have something to do with `zone.js` triggering change detection but why where how? I have no clue :(

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats why

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L146

using async pipe rerenders view.